# Replace "content-area" of themes 404 page with plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, multisite

So I don't want to dive into the whys behind what I need to do but I have a very important piece of code that I need to insert into the 404 page regardless of the theme as a replacement of the content-area div. So below the get_header in replacement of the content-area and before the get_sidebar/get_footer.

Currently I have to install this piece of code into every themes 404 page before I can install it on my multisite, I'd like to accomplish this through a plugin but can't seem to override the themes 404 page.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824792/wordpress-plugin-to-handle-page-not-founds-404 to 'catch' the 404.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Template Page hierarchy, https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png the only template page WP will load is 404.php

But, you might try this in your mu-plugins:

`//Some function to check database to see if this URL should exist
if ( ! checkIfPageExists( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
   //Set 404 Status
   status_header( "404" );
   get_header();
   //do your custom 404 code here
   get_footer();
}`

I'm not sure it'll work, but give it a try